# Why do both promise .then() and .catch() are called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm beginning to write a discord bot with the Discord.js library (version 11.5.1). Promises returned by methods don't work as expected because then() and catch() callbacks are both called if it's successful.

I'm using nodejs version 11.15.0.

In this example, I send a message in the test-bot channel when the bot in logged.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const auth = require('./auth.json');

client.on('ready', () => {
    const guild = client.guilds.find(
        guild => guild.name === 'test');
    const channel = guild.channels.find(
        ch => ch.name === 'test-bot');
    if (!channel) {
        console.error('no channel found');
        return ;
    }
    channel.send('heeeello')
        .then(console.log('cool'))
        .catch(console.error('grrr'));
});
client.login(auth.token);
```

The message is well sended on the discord channel and the console output is:

```
cool
grrr
```

but I don't expect `grrr` in the output.

Comment: Well that means there was an error...?

Comment: maybe output the error message instead of just `'grrr'`

Comment: You aren't passing callback functions to `then` and `catch`. Your `console.log()` expressions will always execute

Comment: I don't agree with the duplicate flag. My mistake was I gave an expression instead of a callback function.

Comment: @rems14 - I'm sure there's an appropriate duplicate to your error - it's a very common mistake :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The then & catch should receive a callback function, you are calling console.log.

```
channel.send('heeeello')
.then(() => console.log('cool') )
.catch(() => console.log('grrr') );
```

Comment: That's true. It works now. Thank you!